# How to use Modules installed with Composer and Firegento in my Magento installation

Tags: module, magento-1, composer

This is a super basic Magento/Composer question — how are users (i.e. me) supposed to make a Magento system aware of packages installed via composer/firegento?

That is — [most of the tutorials](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/composer-with-magento/) I've found cover setting up a `composer.json` file, and I've managed the without a problem.  I can install packages into `vendor` to my heart's content.

They'll also mention adding the following to your `composer.json` so "[something]"  knows where to install the modules

```
"extra":{
    "magento-root-dir":"./"
 }
```

However, what I haven't been able to figure out with the existing documentation is **what command do I need to run in order to copy or symlink the files in `./vendor` into my Magento root**?

The tutorials I've found say [use the magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer project](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer) on GitHub — but this project's README seems more focused on creating your own packages than on basic usage.

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried running "composer install"?  That should be all that is needed.

Comment: @JoeConstant Yes I have — it (looks like?) the single package I installed didn't have the correct requires to make it work.  Working on an answer right now.

Answer (score 5):

The short version: If everything's configured correctly, you don't need to do anything. The way [packages.firegento.com](http://packages.firegento.com/) works is by taking advantage of a [Composer custom installer plugin](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md).  This custom installer plugin handles symlinking or copying the files (depending on the value of `magento-deploystrategy` in the `extra` configuration section)

**However**, somewhere in your composer `require` configuration, you need to include the `magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer` package.

```
"require": {
    "magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer": "*"
},
```

This package installs the composer plugin, which in turn enables the custom installation functionality.   This is why every composer plugin should have this package in its `require` list.

Comment: the last part is wrong, a magento module should not require the installer.

I added an explanation for this to the Readme:
https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer/#should-my-module-require-the-installer

Comment: @Flyingmana I can understand why you'd say that, and it's a laudable goal, but the `connect20/*` packages in the FireGento  repository all had this library auto-added, which means culturally speaking, the project wants its developers to add this packages as a require.  It also makes sense from a usability standpoint, as expecting newbie users to completely grok the composer model seems like a mistake.

Comment: no, simply no!!